# Cache Gradle copy task

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following tasks:

```
task cleanupUI(type: Delete) {
    delete 'src/main/webapp/ui'
}

task unpackUI(type: Copy, dependsOn: cleanupUI) {
    from zipTree(configurations.appPrerequisite.singleFile).matching {
        include 'dist/apps/ui/**'
        eachFile {
            path = path - 'dist/apps/'
        }
        includeEmptyDirs = false
    }
    into 'src/main/webapp/'
}
```

The issue is that the copy task will be executed always because I delete the folder before running the unpackUI task.

Is there any way to only run the cleanupUI if the unpackUI needs to run as well (not cached)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666009/make-a-javaexec-as-delegate-for-using-gradle-build-cache